# How to change the default redirect page for logged out or unregistered users?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

As the title says, I would like to change the default redirect page that Joomla redirects users, when they are logged out or unregistered. I just can't find which file I should edit. I am talking about Joomla 1.5.26 version.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to edit any files.

If your users are using the `mod_login` module to **Logout** you can specify a **Logout Redirection Page** (i.e. a menu item) in the module itself.

If you're using a "User Menu" with a **Logout** menu item you can specify in the menu item a **Logout Redirection URL** — note this a URL not a specific menu item as with the module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend! But... In case that the session has end, and user is trying to see a non public article as unregistered user? In this case user gets **index.php** on my site. Thank you for your time!